# Set default className to an empty string then provide two conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator, classname

I have this condition  `className={errors.firstName ? "invalid" : "valid"}`

But I need it to be default to an empty string if neither of those conditions are met.

I'm struggling to think how to approach this, would appreciate advise as I couldn't find any resources.

I will have to call this multiple times on other text area fields, so I know I need to make this reusable.

Comment: Now you have two status, `true` or `false`. So you should have an initial status like `initialStatus` and then  you can achieve what you want like this: `className={(errors.firstName === 'initialStatus')?"":(errors.firstName)? "invalid":"valid"}`

Comment: If my comment is not clear, tell me if you can have `initialStatus` or not. so i can make a snippet for you

Comment: Okay so I created a variable `intialState` and set it to `false`, I also tried setting it to an empty string, but it still set the default styling as `valid` rather than the `initialState`

Comment: No, You did not understand what I meant. look, just give a initial value to `errors.firstName` called `initialStatus` and then use the condition i've posted.   In short, you need to have three status for `errors.firstName`. You can do this in any way you can think of. And I said the first way that came to my mind. (now you have two status `true` and `false`. you need three. just make another one)

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames for this.

`className={classNames({ invalid: errors.firstName === true }, { valid: errors.firstName === false })`

So if errors.firstName = `true` then the className will be `invalid`. If errors.firstName = `false` then it will be `valid`. If errors.firstName is `undefined` className will be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine your firstName error does not exist in the first place or initialized with null in errors object.

```js
const errors = { firstName: null } // or not having firstName
```

Then the check for having firsName error (which may be of type string e.g. firstName error message or any boolean value).

```
<Component
  className={
    // if you explicitly set it to null use strict in-equality here
    errors.firstName != null ? "" : errors.firstName ? "invalid" : "valid"
  }
/>;
```

you can also prevent setting the default empty string, cause its default :)

```
<Component
  {...(errors.firstName != null && {
    className: errors.firstName ? "invalid" : "valid",
  })}
/>;
```